# Using awk to print ALL spaces within filenames which have a varied number of spaces

Tags: bash, parsing, awk

I'm executing the following using bash and awk to get the potentially space-full filename, colon, file size.  (Column 5 contains the space delimited size, and 9 to EOL the file name):

---

```
src="Desktop"
echo "Constructing $src files list.  `date`"
cat /dev/null > "$src"Files.txt

find -s ~/"$src" -type f -exec ls -l {} \; | 

   awk  '{for(i=9;i<=NF;i++) {printf("%s", $i " ")} print ":" $5}' |

   grep -v ".DS_Store" | grep -v "Icon\r" |

   while read line ; do filespacesize=`basename "$line"`; filesize=`echo "$filespacesize" |

     sed -e 's/ :/:/1'`

     path=`dirname "$line"`;  echo "$filesize:$path" >> "$src"Files.txt ;

  done
```

---

And it works fine, BUT…
If a filename has > 1 space between parts, I only get 1 space between filename parts, and the colon, followed by the filesize.

How can I get the full filename, :, and then the file size?

Comment: You should not parse the output of ls.http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: it may be not a good idea to parse `ls` output; why don't you `stat` the  files instead?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want the following (provided your `find` handles the `printf` option with the `%f`, `%s` and `%h` modifiers):

```
src=Desktop
echo "Constructing $src files list.  $(date)"
find ~/"$src" -type f -printf '%f:%s:%h\n' > "$src"Files.txt
```

Much shorter and much more efficient than your method!

---

This will not discard the `.DS_STORE` and `Icon\r` things… but I'm not really sure what you *really* want to discard. If you want to discard the `.DS_STORE` *directory* altogether:

```
find ~/"$src" -name '.DS_STORE' -type d -prune -o -type f -printf '%f:%s:%h\n' > "$src"Files.txt
```

@guido seems to have guessed what you mean by `grep -v "Icon\r"`: ignore files ending with `Icon`; if this his guess is right, then this will do:

```
find ~/"$src" -name '.DS_STORE' -type d -prune -o ! -name '*Icon' -type f -printf '%f:%s:%h\n' > "$src"Files.txt
```

Comment: i think the Icon\r is for excluding files ending with Icon (\r being the linefeed after each line output of ls -l)